# I dont understand golang, why does my app not call this function and not behave like nodejs

Tags: node.js, go

I am completely new to golang. But I have some knowledge from nodejs

now I would like to learn Go, and here you can see an app that should fire up an webserver, and then it should print hello to the console.

but it seems that after the line

```
http.ListenAndServe(":"+serverportString, nil)
```

it completely stops. In node js it would run concurrently. Do I have a misunderstanding here?

The next line underneath is

```
sayhello()
```

which should start the function to say hello to the console. But it stops right before.

Here you can see the full code

```
// it should start a web server at port 8080
// and it should print hello to the console

package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
    "strconv"
)

var serverport int = 8080

func main(){
    serverportString := strconv.Itoa(serverport)

    http.HandleFunc("/", handler)
    http.ListenAndServe(":"+serverportString, nil)
    sayhello()

}

func handler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fmt.Fprintf(w, "Hi there, I love %s!", r.URL.Path[1:])
}

func sayhello () {
    // now print hello to the console
    fmt.Println("hello")
```

Comment: Try going through some tutorials, and spend a little time with the documentation. (this is covered in [Effective Go](http://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html) BTW)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in the line `http.ListenAndServe(":"+serverportString, nil)`.

[ListenAndServe](http://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#ListenAndServe) Is a blocking call, and usually is left as the last statement of your `main`.

you could launch it in a goroutine with `go http.ListenAndServe(...)` and then the `sayhello()` function will be called, but then the entire program will reach the end of main and all the goroutines will be terminated.